# Using the GPU backend in h2o.xgboost in a rocker based Docker container

Tags: r, docker, h2o, xgboost

I've been trying to get GPU support to work for xgboost via h2o in a [rocker](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker) docker container with little success. Progress so far: [GitHub](https://github.com/seabbs/tidyverse-gpu), [Docker Hub](https://cloud.docker.com/u/seabbs/repository/docker/seabbs/tidyverse-gpu)

I have installed CUDA + nvidia-docker on the host machine and CUDA (9.0 - 9.2) in the container. I'm running the container with the following,

```
nvidia-docker run -d -p 8787:8787 -e USER=tidyverse-gpu -e PASSWORD=tidyverse-gpu --name tidyverse-gpu seabbs/tidyverse-gpu
```

Base Xgboost works with GPU support in both R and Python (and `nvidia-smi` returns usage stats etc when run inside the container). When the GPU backend is enabled in `h2o.xgboost` the following error is returned.

```
Illegal argument(s) for XGBoost model: XGBoost_model_R_1548450637489_3.  Details: ERRR on field: _backend: GPU backend (gpu_id: 0) is not functional. Check CUDA_PATH and/or GPU installation.
```

Initially I had not added the `CUDA_PATH` in the Dockerfile but testing adding this has had no effect.

```
Sys.getenv("CUDA_PATH")
[1] "/usr/local/cuda"
```

The `h2o` startup logs show no issue with the `xgboost` module (that I can see). I've tried rolling back to CUDA 8.0 but this errors in the latest rocker containers as the gcc version being used is not supported by `xgboost`.

Any help would be much appreciated as I don't have a clue :)

Comment: Solution at https://discuss.ropensci.org/t/using-the-gpu-backend-in-h2o-xgboost-in-a-rocker-based-docker-container/1561 - needed to remove the stubs with:` rm -r -f  /usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs`